# Why do i use custom Variable Environment in a hosting website?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, deployment, tornado, cloudcontrol

I am new to hosting world (cloudcontrol), an i got some problem with application credentials, like database administration (mongohq), or google authentification.

So, will i put those variable with some kind of syntaxte (something like `$variable`) in the code, and then make a commandline with key-value as variable-value ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Tornado, it makes it even simpler. Use [tornado.options](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/options.html) and pass environment variables while running the code.

Use following in your Tornado code:

```
define("mysql_host", default="127.0.0.1:3306", help="Main user DB")
define("google_oauth_key", help="Client key for Google Oauth")
```

Then you can access the these values in your rest of your code as:

```
options.mysql_host
options.google_oauth_key
```

When you are running your Tornado script, pass the environment variables:

```
python main.py --mysql_host=$MYSQL_HOST --google_oauth_key=$OAUTH_KEY
```

assuming both `$MYSQL_HOST` and `$OAUTH_KEY` are environment variables. Let me know if you need a full working example or any further help.

example:

First set a environment variable:

```
$export mongo_uri_env=mongodb://alien:12345@kahana.mongohq.com:10067/essog
```

and make changes in your Tornado code:

```
define("mongo_uri", default="127.0.0.1:28017", help="MongoDB URI")
...
...
uri = options.mongo_uri
```

and you would run your code as

```
python main.py --mongo_uri=$mongo_uri_env
```

If you don't want to pass it while running, then you have to read that environment variable directly in your script. For that

```
import os
...
...
uri = os.environ['mongo_uri_env']
```

Comment: i dont get it, so cloudcontrol will use those variables when i put it as a command line in the procfile?

Comment: you want provide some variables to cloud control or use some already set environment variables in your code?

Comment: i will use gmail and mongohq, so i guess there will be new custom envirnment variables? so where to set them, on the code itself?

Comment: I don't understand, can you please elaborate? for example you want your code to connect to mongohq and keep credentials in the environment variables?

Comment: here is the code, https://github.com/abdelouahabb/essog/blob/master/handlers.py#L26 the login information are typed on the code itself, and i want to remove them and let only as variable and only put them when i will launch the application, so noone can see them

Comment: i dont get the code `define("mongo_uri", default="127.0.0.1:28017", help="MongoDB URI")` this is initalizing it, and then after i export the environement variable it will change so i can use the uri specified as mongodb database uri?

Comment: above line specifies Tornado that either `mongo_uri` will passed as argument while running or if not, use default `127.0.0.1:28017` It has nothing to do with environment variables. Read [this](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html)

Comment: i am sorry, but the example, about making environment variable as argument are for local command line? not for cloudcontrol command line?

Comment: ^tried reading documentation? [this](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation) one explains how to do that

Comment: yes, that was my question, where to put those values! https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#add-on-credentials

Comment: yes, but it is explained as it is on a local console, not on cloudcontrol system